# an analysis problem on manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a $n-$dimensional close connected manifold or manifold without boundary and $S$ be a connected close subset homeomorphism to of a $n$-dimensional closed ball $D^n$ (since a manifold is locally compact, $S$ always exists). Let $int(S)$ be the interior of $S$. Is $M-int(S)$ a connected manifold?

I am interested it because I want to simulate the connected sum in my Opengl project,in the case $n=2$ and $M$ can be embedded into $R^3$. I am interested in it.Moreover how can we deduce some topology properties on $M-int(S)$ such as its homology.For example if $M$ is a convex close subset in $R^n$, and we dig out the interior of a small ball $D^n$ in $M$, then $M-int(D^n)$ should take $S^{(n-1)}$ as its retract kernel so homology group $H_k(M-int(D^n)) = \mathbb{Z}$ iff $k=n-1$. (Is my calculation right?)

Comment: You forgot to assume that $M$ is connected.

Comment: Really sorry uh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Assuming $M$ is connected, the answer is yes. Indeed, any path joining $x$ and $y$ passing throuhg $S$ can be deformed to a path passing only on the boundary $\partial S$.

2) Your computation is indeed correct.

Comment: Thank you and give you a upvote!I forget to assume $M$ is connected.However a connected manifold is not always path-connected since topologist's sine curve is a typical counterexample.How to explain this?

Comment: The topologist's curve is not a manifold. A manifold is always locally connected.

Comment: @Muse_China: for a standard manifold, we have always connected $\Leftrightarrow$ path connected, because a manifold is locally path-connected.

Comment: Yeah.I make a mistake.Thank you for pointing out.And a further question,is topology structure $M-int(S)$ depends on the choice of $S$?

Comment: @Muse_China : I would say that it does not depend on the choice of $S$. Here is a sketch of the proof : take a path between the center of $S$ and the center of $S'$. There is a diffeomorphism $f : M \to M$ with $f(S) = S'$, obtained as integration of a suitable vector field.